# Networkx: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to make a graph network in Networkx, but after having copied the following code directly from a textbook I get the error:
"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object". I also looked at a [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/classes.graph.html) example but it uses pretty much the same format of code. What is wrong here?

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1,2)

G.add_nodes_from([3,4,5,6,7])
G.add_edges_from([(3,4),(3,5),(5,6)])

print(nx.adjacency_matrix(G))
G.edges[3][4]                      # ERROR HERE 
G.edges[3][4]['color']='blue'      # ERROR HERE
```

Comment: The different between your code and the sample code is that they have `G.edge` where you have `G.edges`.  Spelling matters.

Comment: @TimRoberts I've tested G.edge but it comes back with "'Graph' object has no attribute 'edge'. Did you mean: 'edges'?"

Comment: Replace `G.edges[3][4]` with `G.edges[3, 4]`. Look [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html).

Comment: Hmm.  The documentation says `G.edge[3][4]` or `G[3][4]`.  Not edges.  I wonder if you have a different version.  https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/classes.graph.html ,  What does `print(g.edges)` show you?